# RadioButtonList items with different colors?

Tags: c#, repeater, radiobuttonlist

have repeater which display question with answers
As

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound1" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: left">
                    <%# Eval("ExamQuestionsText")%>   (Question Level <%# Eval("QuetionLevel")%>)  
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="DeleteQuestion" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Item?');"  runat="server" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></asp:LinkButton> 
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Update" CommandName="Update" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>'   runat="server" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: left">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

how assign colors for right answers  without foreach ?

Comment: What does this webforms code have to do with MVC?

Comment: Tag ASP.NET only and not MVC.